# Split amount in different columns

Tags: sql, split

```
id amount
1 4502,52
2 1500
3 2343,24
4 234,05
```

I want to split the amount with a column of the euro amount, a column for the cents:

```
id  amount   euro   cent
1   4502,52   4502   52
2   1500      1500    0
3   2343,24   2343   24
```

Comment: What data type is the `amount` column?

Comment: Also, please provide the current query that you are using (SELECT, tablename, etc). The answer will be in the form of an updated query.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that amount is number field:

```
select id, amount, trunc(amount) as euro, 
sign(amount)*(amount - trunc(amount))*100 as cent from dual;
```

Cheers!!